# Should we nuke the [calculations], [research] and [malfunction] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

These tags have about a dozen questions each.

[calculations](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/calculations) and [research](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/research) are too general and ambiguous. A few questions tagged [research](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/research) do relate to hardware and software for academia, but even then there is ambiguity (and they're not great questions anyway).

[malfunction](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/malfunction) might be ok, and it *could* be made a synonym of [failure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/failure) - but "failure" is a slightly different, stronger term.

(The criterion I used to spot these is: *would anyone ever "favourite" this tag?*)

Comment: *> would anyone ever "favourite" this tag?* — nah. I'd get rid of them.

Comment: I wouldn't, but surely there's a guy somewhere who's into math and calculating ... calculations?

Comment: @Daniel Maybe... but I doubt that many people have *that much* of a fetish for doing mostly trivial sums on such a wide variety of topics.

Comment: I agree, that's why one of those up votes is mine ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed, these 3 are all burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: TROGDOR the Burninator!